# Custom messages for user_pass_reset

Tags: 7, hooks, status-messages

I would like to customize the messages for one time login links (i.e. password reset links). In some cases, I redirect the user to the login page. In these cases, it does not make sense to have "Please request a new one using the form below."

Is there a hook or module I can use to add some logic to that message? (I can do a global override with String Overrides, but am looking for more conditional messages.)

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: Whoops, Drupal 7. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the email message for a password reset. You can use `hook_mail_alter` to change the email contents before it's sent out to the user.

If you mean the form the user sees on the webpage, then you can use `hook_form_alter` to change the verbiage shown on the screen.

### Edit

override the displayed form with the reset button to goto your own form_submit action. In your custom module action, simply copy and paste user_pass_reset function body into your own function and tweak it as needed to change the messages (careful).

Comment: I actually mean the messages that are shown when a link is clicked. Specifically, `drupal_set_message(t('You have tried to use a one-time login link that has either been used or is no longer valid. Please request a new one using the form below.'), 'error');` in `user_pass_reset`.

Comment: see my edit to my answer.

Comment: Then he should alter the reset link menu, not the form. The ```user_pass_reset``` is a menu callback.

Comment: Ops, sorry, you are right, it's form. I always use the link with the /login at the end and forgot is managed by a form not a direct link.

Comment: Would something like this work? https://www.ignoredbydinosaurs.com/posts/40-altering-drupal-password-reset-process

Answer (score 0):

Those messages are pretty harcoded in user module in the file `user.pages.inc`, `user_pass_reset` function.

There's no hook to alter drupal set messages, but if you want to suppress certain messages you have luck with the module [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages):

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end
>   users.

Features:

- Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
- Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
- Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
- Disable all filtering for specific users.
- Disable all filtering for specific paths.
- Apply filtering only for specific paths.
- Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.

## About using rules

There is an issue about this: [Is it possible to unset or override system messages with Rules?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1102916)

Comment: If I disable them, is there a way (either programatically or via Rules) to set a new message? I was looking for a Rule event for "One time login link was clicked" or something, but did not find any. (Other modules offer Rules integration but do not play well with Password Reset Landing Page, which I also use.)

Comment: Not possible with rules at the moment, answer updated.